# javascript setInterval() syntax error in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, arrow-functions

I am trying to execute some javascript with setInterval() method, below is my code

```
if(have_access){
        let clock = setInterval(() => {   // getting error here
            clearInterval(clock);
            clock = null;
            document.getElementById('link_permissions').style.display = 'block';
        }, 200);

    }else{          
        let clock = setInterval(() => {
            clearInterval(clock);
            clock = null;
            document.getElementById('link_permissions').style.display = 'none';
        }, 200);
    }
```

This code is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but getting Syntax error in IE11. What would be the work around to make this work in IE too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IE does not support arrow functions. In your build process, transform your code to ES5 with a transpiler like Babel.

Comment: Arrow functions are not supported in IE11 [can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions).

Comment: Thanks guys, learned a new thing today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it was mentioned in the comments arrow functions are not supported in IE.

Simply change it to this:

```
if (have_access) {
  let clock = setInterval(function() {
    clearInterval(clock);
    clock = null;
    document.getElementById('link_permissions').style.display = 'block';
  }, 200);

} else {
  let clock = setInterval(function() {
    clearInterval(clock);
    clock = null;
    document.getElementById('link_permissions').style.display = 'none';
  }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.